# Some confusion with Closure of Operations

Tags: domain-driven-design

From DDD: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software ( pg 268 ):

> If implementer has state that is used in the computation, then
>   implementer is effectively an argument of the operation, so the
>   arguments and return value should be of the same type as the
>   implementer. Such an operation is closed under the set of instances of
>   that type.

a) I understand that making *arguments*, *return value* and *implementer* of same type would simplify an interpretation of operation, but  is author suggesting that even though conceptually it would make more sense for *arguments* and *return value* not to be of the same type ( say `ImplType` ) as implementer, we should still try to force them to be `ImplType`, even if it means we'll have to sacrifice a bit of conceptual clarity?

b) My thinking is, if it made more sense for *arguments* and *return value* to be of type `ImplType`, then we would already define them as such,  even if we didn't know anything about *Closure of Operations* and its benefits. Shouldn't the fact that we initially made them of different type be an indication that conceptually it is better they're not of type `ImplType`?

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think a key quote about closure of operations is:

> **Where it fits**, define an operation whose return type is the same as
>   the type of its argument(s).

The idea is that closure of operations establishes some desirable restrictions on behaviors, but it should be applied where it fits. The statement about an implementer with state being regarded as an argument to the operation is based on how OOP is implemented. Behind the scenes, the runtime passes an initialized **this** argument to all class methods. In this way, each method that implements an operation can be regarded as a static method which accepts the implementing type as the first argument. Viewing the operation in this way attempts to make everything about it explicit thereby reducing dependencies.

The notion of closure of operations was borrowed from mathematics, abstract algebra and group theory specifically. In mathematics, being a pure declarative model, this principle has far many applications than it does in enterprise development, however we can still get some benefit from it.